# Inode structure - record rec_len?

Tags: linux, inode, ext2

I need to know how to exactly computed record rec_len. How it is count ?

[image]

Comment: It looks like all records are a multiple of 4 bytes, and unused bytes are padded with 0. That's why the `.` is `name_len=1` and padded with `\0\0\0`; and why the `..` is `name_len=2` and padded with `\0\0`. You should probably just lookup [the ext2 spec](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ext2+filesystem+spec). There are probably other cases to consider that may need special handling.

Answer (score 0):

the **inode** is `4bytes` + `1byte` of the **file_type** + `1byte` of the **name_len** + `2bytes` of the **rec_len** + name data which is `1byte` per character and the record must be padded to x4 ( **4 bytes boundaries** ) that's why we add the `"\0"` for padding

---

for the first example `.` you have 4+1+1+2+4=12 and the same for others